# Null pointer exception while inserting date value

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to insert date using DatePicker in sqlte in my android application. My application crashes when I click on Submit button while giving me a Nullpointer Exception

I have tried changing Data type of date from Double to Numeric.

```
 package com.example.ameyz;


import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener,DatePickerFragment.DateDialogListener {


    private static String STRING_EMPTY = "";
    private static final String DIALOG_DATE = "DialogDate";
    static Spinner sItemsWorkerbrick1 = null;
    private static int selectedWorkerIdbrick1 = 0;
    private static boolean isEditWorkerbrick1 = false;
    CommonDBHelper dbHelper = null;
    ImageView calender;
    private EditText dateworkerbrick1;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dbHelper = new CommonDBHelper(this);

        populateSpinnerWorkerbrick1();
        calender = findViewById(R.id.calender);

        Button addWorkerbrick1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddWorkerBrick1);

        calender.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                DatePickerFragment dialog = new DatePickerFragment();
                dialog.show(manager, DIALOG_DATE);
            }
        });
        addWorkerbrick1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addNewWorkerbrick1();

            }
        });
    }

    private void addNewWorkerbrick1() {
        Brick1WorkerDetails movieDetails = new Brick1WorkerDetails();

        EditText workerNameBrick1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtWorkerNameAddBrick1);
        EditText salaryworkerBrick1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSalaryAddWorkerBrick1);
        EditText loanworkerBrick1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLoanAddWorkerbrick1);
        EditText paidloanworkerBrick1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPaidAddWorkerbrick1);
        EditText unpaidloanworkerBrick1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUnpaidAddWorkerbrick1);
        EditText dateworkerbrick1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtDateAddWorkerbrick1);
        if (!STRING_EMPTY.equals(workerNameBrick1.getText().toString()) &&
                !STRING_EMPTY.equals(salaryworkerBrick1.getText().toString()) &&
                !STRING_EMPTY.equals(loanworkerBrick1.getText().toString()) &&
                !STRING_EMPTY.equals(paidloanworkerBrick1.getText().toString()) &&
                !STRING_EMPTY.equals(unpaidloanworkerBrick1.getText().toString()) &&
        !STRING_EMPTY.equals(dateworkerbrick1.getText().toString())) {
            movieDetails.setWorkerNameBrick1(workerNameBrick1.getText().toString());
            movieDetails.setSalaryworkerBrick1(Integer.parseInt(salaryworkerBrick1.getText().toString()));
            movieDetails.setLoanworkerBrick1(Integer.parseInt(loanworkerBrick1.getText().toString()));
            movieDetails.setPaidloanworkerBrick1(Integer.parseInt(paidloanworkerBrick1.getText().toString()));
            movieDetails.setUnpaidloanworkerBrick1(Integer.parseInt(unpaidloanworkerBrick1.getText().toString()));
            movieDetails.setWorkerdate(dateworkerbrick1.getText().toString());
            dbHelper.addWorkerbrick1(movieDetails);
            populateSpinnerWorkerbrick1();
            workerNameBrick1.setText("");
            salaryworkerBrick1.setText("");
            loanworkerBrick1.setText("");
            paidloanworkerBrick1.setText("");
            unpaidloanworkerBrick1.setText("");
            dateworkerbrick1.setText("");
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "One or more fields left empty!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }



    }

    private void populateSpinnerWorkerbrick1() {
        List<Brick1WorkerDetails> movieDetailsList = dbHelper.getAllWorkersbrick1();
        List movieSpinnerList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < movieDetailsList.size(); i++) {
            Brick1WorkerDetails movieDetailsVO = movieDetailsList.get(i);
            WorkerBrick1SpinnerVO movieSpinnerVO = new WorkerBrick1SpinnerVO(movieDetailsVO.getWorkerBrick1Id(),
                    movieDetailsVO.getWorkerNameBrick1());
            movieSpinnerList.add(movieSpinnerVO);
        }
        if (movieDetailsList.size() == 0) {
            LinearLayout displayArea42 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.displayAreaWorkerBrick1);
            displayArea42.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

            LinearLayout editButton42 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.editButtonWorkerbrick1);
            editButton42.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

            LinearLayout editArea42 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.editAreaWorkerBrick1);
            editArea42.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

            LinearLayout movieSpinnerLayout42 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.movieSpinnerLayoutWorkerBrick1);
            movieSpinnerLayout42.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

        } else {
            LinearLayout movieSpinnerLayout42 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.movieSpinnerLayoutWorkerBrick1);
            movieSpinnerLayout42.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, movieSpinnerList);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sItemsWorkerbrick1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.movieSpinnerWorkerBrick1);
        sItemsWorkerbrick1.setAdapter(adapter);
        sItemsWorkerbrick1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }


    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        WorkerBrick1SpinnerVO movieSpinnerVO = (WorkerBrick1SpinnerVO) sItemsWorkerbrick1.getSelectedItem();
        int movieId = movieSpinnerVO.getWorkerIdbrick1();

        selectedWorkerIdbrick1 = movieId;

        Brick1WorkerDetails movieDetailsVO = dbHelper.getWorkerBrick1(movieId);

        TextView txtWorkerNameDisplay42 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtWorkerNameDisplayBrick1);
        txtWorkerNameDisplay42.setText(movieDetailsVO.getWorkerNameBrick1());

        TextView txtSalaryDisplay42 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSalaryDisplayWorkerBrick1);
        String salarybrick1 = Integer.toString(movieDetailsVO.getSalaryworkerBrick1());
        txtSalaryDisplay42.setText(salarybrick1);

        TextView txtLoanDisplay42 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLoanDisplayWorkerBrick1);
        String loanbrick1 = Integer.toString(movieDetailsVO.getLoanworkerBrick1());
        txtLoanDisplay42.setText(loanbrick1);

        TextView txtPaidworkerbrick1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPaidDisplayWorkerBrick1);
        String paidworkerbrick1 = Integer.toString(movieDetailsVO.getPaidloanworkerBrick1());
        txtPaidworkerbrick1.setText(paidworkerbrick1);

        TextView txtUnpaidworkerbrick1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUnpaidDisplayWorkerBrick1);
        String unpaidworkerbrick1 = Integer.toString(movieDetailsVO.getUnpaidloanworkerBrick1());
        txtUnpaidworkerbrick1.setText(unpaidworkerbrick1);

        TextView txtdateworker = findViewById(R.id.txtDateDisplayWorkerBrick1);
        txtdateworker.setText(movieDetailsVO.getWorkerdate());


        LinearLayout displayArea42 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.displayAreaWorkerBrick1);
        displayArea42.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);

        LinearLayout editButton42 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.editButtonWorkerbrick1);
        editButton42.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);

        Button btnEdit42 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEditWorkerBrick1);
        btnEdit42.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editWorkerbrick1();
            }
        });
        Button btnDelete42 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteWorkerBrick1);
        btnDelete42.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                deleteWorkerbrick1();
            }
        });

    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
    private void editWorkerbrick1() {

        Brick1WorkerDetails movieDetailsVO = null;
        EditText workerNameBrick1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtWorkerNameEditBrick1);
        EditText salaryworkerBrick1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSalaryEditWorkerBrick1);
        EditText loanworkerBrick1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLoanEditWorkerBrick1);
        EditText paidloanworkerBrick1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPaidEditWorkerBrick1);
        EditText unpaidloanworkerBrick1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUnpaidEditWorkerBrick1);
        EditText  dateworkerbrick1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtDateEditWorkerBrick1);



        if (isEditWorkerbrick1) {

            if (!STRING_EMPTY.equals(workerNameBrick1.getText().toString()) &&
                    !STRING_EMPTY.equals(salaryworkerBrick1.getText().toString()) &&
                    !STRING_EMPTY.equals(loanworkerBrick1.getText().toString()) &&
                    !STRING_EMPTY.equals(paidloanworkerBrick1.getText().toString()) &&
                    !STRING_EMPTY.equals(unpaidloanworkerBrick1.getText().toString()) &&
                     !STRING_EMPTY.equals(dateworkerbrick1.getText().toString())) {

                movieDetailsVO = new Brick1WorkerDetails();

                LinearLayout displayArea42 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.displayAreaWorkerBrick1);
                displayArea42.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                LinearLayout editArea42 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.editAreaWorkerBrick1);
                editArea42.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
                Button btnDelete42 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteWorkerBrick1);
                btnDelete42.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);

                movieDetailsVO.setWorkerBrick1Id(selectedWorkerIdbrick1);
                movieDetailsVO.setWorkerNameBrick1(workerNameBrick1.getText().toString());
                movieDetailsVO.setSalaryworkerBrick1(Integer.parseInt(salaryworkerBrick1.getText().toString()));
                movieDetailsVO.setLoanworkerBrick1(Integer.parseInt(loanworkerBrick1.getText().toString()));
                movieDetailsVO.setPaidloanworkerBrick1(Integer.parseInt(paidloanworkerBrick1.getText().toString()));
                movieDetailsVO.setUnpaidloanworkerBrick1(Integer.parseInt(unpaidloanworkerBrick1.getText().toString()));
                movieDetailsVO.setWorkerdate(dateworkerbrick1.getText().toString());
                dbHelper.updateWorkerBrick1(movieDetailsVO);
                populateSpinnerWorkerbrick1();
                sItemsWorkerbrick1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.movieSpinnerWorkerBrick1);
                sItemsWorkerbrick1.setSelection(getSpinnerPositionWorkerbrick1(sItemsWorkerbrick1));
                isEditWorkerbrick1 = false;

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "One or more fields left empty!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            movieDetailsVO = dbHelper.getWorkerBrick1(selectedWorkerIdbrick1);
            LinearLayout displayArea42 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.displayAreaWorkerBrick1);
            displayArea42.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
            LinearLayout editArea42 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.editAreaWorkerBrick1);
            editArea42.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
            Button btnDelete42 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteWorkerBrick1);
            btnDelete42.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);

            workerNameBrick1.setText(movieDetailsVO.getWorkerNameBrick1());
            salaryworkerBrick1.setText(Integer.toString(movieDetailsVO.getSalaryworkerBrick1()));
            loanworkerBrick1.setText(Integer.toString(movieDetailsVO.getLoanworkerBrick1()));
            paidloanworkerBrick1.setText(Integer.toString(movieDetailsVO.getPaidloanworkerBrick1()));
            unpaidloanworkerBrick1.setText(Integer.toString(movieDetailsVO.getUnpaidloanworkerBrick1()));
            dateworkerbrick1.setText(movieDetailsVO.getWorkerdate());
            isEditWorkerbrick1 = true;
        }
    }

    private int getSpinnerPositionWorkerbrick1(Spinner spinner) {
        Adapter adapter = spinner.getAdapter();
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            WorkerBrick1SpinnerVO movieSpinnerVO = (WorkerBrick1SpinnerVO) adapter.getItem(i);
            if (selectedWorkerIdbrick1 == movieSpinnerVO.getWorkerIdbrick1()) {
                return i;
            }

        }
        return 0;
    }
    private void deleteWorkerbrick1() {
        dbHelper.deleteWorkerbrick1(selectedWorkerIdbrick1);
        populateSpinnerWorkerbrick1();
    }


    @Override
    public void onFinishDialog(Date date) {
        dateworkerbrick1.setText(formatDate(date));


    }
    public String formatDate(Date date){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String workdate = sdf.format(date);
        return workdate;
    }
}
```

Below is the class where I have used Date Picker to set date

DatePickerFragment.java

```
package com.example.ameyz;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private DatePicker datePicker;

    public interface DateDialogListener{
        void onFinishDialog(Date date);
    }


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())
                .inflate(R.layout.dialog_date,null);

        datePicker = (DatePicker) v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_date_date_picker);
        return new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setView(v)
                .setTitle("Date")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                int year = datePicker.getYear();
                                int mon = datePicker.getMonth();
                                int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
                                Date date=  new GregorianCalendar(year,mon,day).getTime();
                                DateDialogListener activity =(DateDialogListener)getActivity();
                                activity.onFinishDialog(date);
                                dismiss();
                            }
                        })
                .create();


    }




}
```

This is the DBHelper class where I have stored all the columns of my table including other code of database upgrading and downgrading.

CommonDBHelper.java

```
package com.example.ameyz;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CommonDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "trump";
    public static final String WORKER_BRICK1 = "worker_brick1";
    public static final String KEY_WORKER_IDBRICK1 = "workerIdbrick1";
    public static final String KEY_WORKER_NAMEBRICK1 = "workerNamebrick1";
    public static final String KEY_WORKERSALARYBRICK1 = "workerSalarybrick1";
    public static final String KEY_WORKERLOANBRICK1 = "workerLoanbrick1";
    public static final String KEY_WORKERPAIDBRICK1 = "workerPaidbrick1";
    public static final String KEY_WORKERUNPAIDBRICK1 = "workerUnpaidbrick1";
    public static final String KEY_WORKERDATEBRICK1 = "workerdatebrick1";



    //Create Table query for Workers Brick1

    private static final String SQL_CREATE_WORKERBRICK1 =
            "CREATE TABLE " + WORKER_BRICK1 + " (" +
                    KEY_WORKER_IDBRICK1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    KEY_WORKER_NAMEBRICK1 + " TEXT, " +
                    KEY_WORKERSALARYBRICK1 + "  INTEGER, " +
                    KEY_WORKERLOANBRICK1 + "  INTEGER, " +
                    KEY_WORKERPAIDBRICK1 + " INTEGER, " +
                    KEY_WORKERUNPAIDBRICK1 + " INTEGER, " +
                    KEY_WORKERDATEBRICK1 + " NUMERIC " +
                    ")";

    public CommonDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_WORKERBRICK1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + WORKER_BRICK1);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        this.onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }

    // Get all worker for Brick1
    public long addWorkerbrick1(Brick1WorkerDetails movie) {

        // Gets the data repository in write mode
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        //Create a map having movie details to be inserted
        ContentValues movie_details = new ContentValues();
        movie_details.put(KEY_WORKER_NAMEBRICK1,movie.getWorkerNameBrick1());
        movie_details.put(KEY_WORKERSALARYBRICK1, movie.getSalaryworkerBrick1());
        movie_details.put(KEY_WORKERLOANBRICK1, movie.getLoanworkerBrick1());
        movie_details.put(KEY_WORKERPAIDBRICK1, movie.getPaidloanworkerBrick1());
        movie_details.put(KEY_WORKERUNPAIDBRICK1, movie.getUnpaidloanworkerBrick1());
        movie_details.put(KEY_WORKERDATEBRICK1, movie.getWorkerdate());


        long newRowId = db.insert(WORKER_BRICK1,null, movie_details);
        db.close();
        return newRowId;
    }

    // Get all Workers of Brick1
    public List getAllWorkersbrick1() {
        List movieDetailsList = new ArrayList();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + WORKER_BRICK1
                + " ORDER BY " + KEY_WORKER_IDBRICK1 + " DESC";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        //if TABLE has rows
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            //Loop through the table rows
            do {
                Brick1WorkerDetails movieDetails = new Brick1WorkerDetails();
                movieDetails.setWorkerBrick1Id(cursor.getInt(0));
                movieDetails.setWorkerNameBrick1(cursor.getString(1));
                movieDetails.setSalaryworkerBrick1(cursor.getInt(2));
                movieDetails.setLoanworkerBrick1(cursor.getInt(3));
                movieDetails.setPaidloanworkerBrick1(cursor.getInt(4));
                movieDetails.setUnpaidloanworkerBrick1(cursor.getInt(5));
                movieDetails.setWorkerdate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CommonDBHelper.KEY_WORKERDATEBRICK1)));
                //Add Workers details to list
                movieDetailsList.add(movieDetails);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        return movieDetailsList;
    }

    public Brick1WorkerDetails getWorkerBrick1(int movie_id) {

        Brick1WorkerDetails movieDetails = new Brick1WorkerDetails();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        //specify the columns to be fetched
        String[] columns = {KEY_WORKER_IDBRICK1, KEY_WORKER_NAMEBRICK1, KEY_WORKERSALARYBRICK1, KEY_WORKERLOANBRICK1, KEY_WORKERPAIDBRICK1, KEY_WORKERUNPAIDBRICK1, KEY_WORKERDATEBRICK1};
        //Select condition
        String selection = KEY_WORKER_IDBRICK1 + " = ?";
        //Arguments for selection
        String[] selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(movie_id)};


        Cursor cursor = db.query(WORKER_BRICK1, columns, selection,
                selectionArgs, null, null, null);
        if (null != cursor) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            movieDetails.setWorkerBrick1Id(cursor.getInt(0));
            movieDetails.setWorkerNameBrick1(cursor.getString(1));
            movieDetails.setSalaryworkerBrick1(cursor.getInt(2));
            movieDetails.setLoanworkerBrick1(cursor.getInt(3));
            movieDetails.setPaidloanworkerBrick1(cursor.getInt(4));
            movieDetails.setUnpaidloanworkerBrick1(cursor.getInt(5));
            movieDetails.setWorkerdate(cursor.getString(6));

        }
        db.close();
        return movieDetails;

    }

    public void updateWorkerBrick1(Brick1WorkerDetails movie) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String workerIds[] = {String.valueOf(movie.getWorkerBrick1Id())};

        ContentValues movie_details = new ContentValues();
        movie_details.put(KEY_WORKER_NAMEBRICK1, movie.getWorkerNameBrick1());
        movie_details.put(KEY_WORKERSALARYBRICK1, movie.getSalaryworkerBrick1());
        movie_details.put(KEY_WORKERLOANBRICK1, movie.getLoanworkerBrick1());
        movie_details.put(KEY_WORKERPAIDBRICK1, movie.getPaidloanworkerBrick1());
        movie_details.put(KEY_WORKERUNPAIDBRICK1, movie.getUnpaidloanworkerBrick1());
        movie_details.put(KEY_WORKERDATEBRICK1,movie.getWorkerdate());
        db.update(WORKER_BRICK1, movie_details, KEY_WORKER_IDBRICK1 + " = ?", workerIds);
        db.close();
    }
    public void deleteWorkerbrick1(int movieId) {
        String workerIds[] = {String.valueOf(movieId)};
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(WORKER_BRICK1, KEY_WORKER_IDBRICK1 + " = ?", workerIds);
        db.close();
    }


}
```

Logcat error

```
Process: com.example.ameyz, PID: 29145
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.ameyz.MainActivity.onFinishDialog(MainActivity.java:281)
        at com.example.ameyz.DatePickerFragment$1.onClick(DatePickerFragment.java:41)
        at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6635)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: check all your EditText id properly in layout file and mentioned in MainActivity class while binding. Make sure you've given the same id in **findViewById(-)**

Comment: If you know what a NullPointerException is, then you should phrase your question to focus on why the thing that causes the NullPointerException (ie the **field** `dateworkerbrick1`) is null. That changes the dynamics of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your `dateworkerbrick1` field is null since you're never assigning any value to it:

```
private EditText dateworkerbrick1;
```

Initialise it to a non-null value before calling a method on it.

In two other methods you have a local variable by the same name which might cause some confusion:

```
EditText dateworkerbrick1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtDateAddWorkerbrick1);
```

That also gives you a hint how to assign a value to the field.

Comment: What value should I assign? are you talking about  local variable 'EditText dateworkerbrick1 ' or all the others too?

Comment: By non-null , what value do you recommend to put in it? That EditText is where I put the date by clicking on Date Picker. I have put 'DD-MM-YYYY' in the hint. I did tried changing the local variable names but its not helping either.